# Laravel: Print first array as table header and other array as table body data?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

My array response is as shown in the picture below. I want to display the first row's data as a table header and others as table body data. How do I display the array as a dynamic table header and body with the below code?

```
<table  class="table hover">
      <thead>
         <tr> 
            <th></th>                        
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

[image]

Comment: In your blade view, assuming the variable holding the array is called conracts `$controller`

Comment: $data = json_decode($request->data, true);
 return view('review_contact',compact('data'));

Comment: Sorry, started to write the comment by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

```
<table class="table hover">
    @foreach($contacts as $contact)
        @if($loop->first)
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach($contact as $header)
                        <th>{{ $header }}</th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        @else
            <tr>
                @foreach($contact as $value)
                    <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ok now I have upload some attachments that show that I do the same and getting this result.

This is my `$data` I am passing to the blade

[image]

and this is my `blade file` where I am writing the already provided `blade code`

[image]

And this is the final output

[image]

**New Code:** But you can also try this new code this also give the same result if you data array is like this

```
<table class="table hover">
        @foreach($contacts as $contact)
            <tr>
                @foreach($contact as $value)
                    @if($loop->parent->first)
                        <th>{{ $value }}</th>
                    @else
                        <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

This first line `@if($loop->parent->first)` is used to check if this is `first iteration` if yes then show the `<th>` which is create table heading if `not first iteration` then create the `<td>`.

Comment: While i tried to save it why header items show second iteration?

Comment: I have edit the code can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

In your blade view, assuming the variable holding the array is called `$contacts`

```
<table class="table hover">
@foreach($contacts as $contact)
    @if($loop->first)
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{!! implode('</th><th>', array_map('ucwords', str_replace('_', ' ', $contact))) !!}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @else
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $contact[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $contact[1] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $contact[2] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $contact[3] }}, {{ $contact[4] }}</td>
            </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For header you could probably do `<th>{{ implode('</th><th>', $contact) }}</th>` maybe, or maybe not. No way to test this on my phone

Comment: Undefined array key 1 (throws Error)

Comment: Modify the variables as you need to, I'm on my phone right now, but the trick is that you use `$loop->first` to make the first iteration different than the rest. Start with doing `print_r($contact)` on the first iteration to see how that array is structured

Comment: Besides, do you really need the header to be dynamic? The header is normally hard coded and the rest of the table is formatted to fit the header...

Comment: I tested this code with the sample array you provided and that works perfectly. I beautified the column names a bit for you as well.

Comment: I have tested with your code. The problem is data means header section works fine. But when i tried to second row to so on..it throws error  `Undefined array key 1`

Comment: Your 5th array has only 1 value... maybe remove that array before sending through the loop